# Agregar FK a tabla (association) en el modelo, sequlize en node (angular fullstack)

Tags: angularjs, nodejs, sequelize.js

necesito agregar FK en las tablas, lo he probado de la siguiente manera y no logro hacerlo.

Index.html

```html
db.Country = db.sequelize.import('../api/country/country.model');
db.City = db.sequelize.import('../api/city/city.model');
module.exports = db;
```

city.model.js

```js
export default function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var City = sequelize.define('City', {
    _id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
    info: DataTypes.STRING,
    active: DataTypes.BOOLEAN
  }, {
      associate: function (db) {
        City.belongsTo(db.Country);
      }
    });
  return City;
}
```

country.model.js

```js
export default function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var Country = sequelize.define('Country', {
    _id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
    info: DataTypes.STRING
   }, {
      associate: function (db) {
        Country.hasMany(db.City);
      }
    });
  return Country;
}
```

Pd: Estoy usando postgres

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucione agregando lo siguiente al modelo.

```js
 countryId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      references: {
        model: 'Countries',
        key: '_id'
      }
    }
```